# How do I hide the warning message "connect_to localhost port 9000: failed." when I do a reverse SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, xdebug

I am currently using a reverse SSH tunnel

```
ssh user@myserver.com -R 9000:localhost:9000
```

to forward [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) (a PHP debugging tool) packets from my server to my local machine. I also have the feature `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` so that any site I visit (including AJAX calls) on `myserver.com` forwards a Xdebug packet.

However, if I don't want to currently debug PHP and I'm not listening to port 9000 on my local machine, then my SSH session gives the warning

```
connect_to localhost port 9000: failed.
```

Since I browse through a lot of pages on `myserver.com`, my bash shell will easily fill up with hundreds of these messages.

So is there a way to hide these warning messages?

Answer (score 3):

`ssh -q` seems to have done the trick. It now ignores the `connect_to localhost port 9000: failed.`, but if you have other terminals with other `ssh` sessions to the same host, then you'll need to restart them with the `-q` flag too.